# Getting connection timeout error when running simple data fusion pipeline to export data from Bigquery and write to GCS

Tags: google-cloud-data-fusion

I am trying to use google Data fusion service, i created a simple pipeline which will extract data from BigQuery and load that data back to GCS in json formate but when i am running the pipeline i am getting the below error.

> java.io.IOException: com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException:
>   java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out (Connection timed out)
>     at
>   io.cdap.cdap.common.ssh.DefaultSSHSession.(DefaultSSHSession.java:82)
>   ~[na:na]  at
>   io.cdap.cdap.internal.app.runtime.distributed.remote.RemoteExecutionTwillPreparer.lambda$start$0(RemoteExecutionTwillPreparer.java:429)
>   ~[na:na]

i provided the all the necessary access to data fusion instance service account.
below are the access which i provided.

```
BigQuery Admin
Compute Admin
Cloud Data Fusion Admin
Cloud Data Fusion API Service Agent
Dataproc Administrator
Storage Admin
computer network viewer
```

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56506384/fail-to-start-program-run-program-run

Answer (score 3):

Cloud Data Fusion requires that port 22 be open to the firewall on the customer project.
Is this something that you can modify in your project's firewall rules?

Comment: Thanks @Ali for the response i am using the default vpc network and i already apply the firewall rule to open the port 22. Do i need to do something else?

Comment: Can you retry the pipeline run? If you get the same error, could you please share your firewall rules list?