# Fail to start program run program_run

Tags: google-cloud-data-fusion

The source of the error:

```
io.cdap.cdap.internal.app.runtime.distributed.remote.RemoteExecutionTwillRunnerService#543-runtime-startup-1
```

The error message:

> java.io.IOException: com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException:
>   java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out (Connection timed out)
>     at
>   io.cdap.cdap.common.ssh.DefaultSSHSession.(DefaultSSHSession.java:82)
>   ~[na:na]  at
>   io.cdap.cdap.internal.app.runtime.distributed.remote.RemoteExecutionTwillPreparer.lambda$start$0(RemoteExecutionTwillPreparer.java:429)
>   ~[na:na]  at
>   io.cdap.cdap.internal.app.runtime.distributed.remote.RemoteExecutionTwillRunnerService$ControllerFactory.lambda$create$0(RemoteExecutionTwillRunnerService.java:519)
>   ~[na:na]  at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_212]   at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_212]   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_212]   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_212]   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_212] Caused by: com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException:
>   java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out (Connection timed out)
>     at com.jcraft.jsch.Util.createSocket(Util.java:349)
>   ~[com.jcraft.jsch-0.1.54.jar:na]  at
>   com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:215)
>   ~[com.jcraft.jsch-0.1.54.jar:na]  at
>   com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:183)
>   ~[com.jcraft.jsch-0.1.54.jar:na]  at
>   io.cdap.cdap.common.ssh.DefaultSSHSession.(DefaultSSHSession.java:79)
>   ~[na:na]  ... 7 common frames omitted Caused by:
>   java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out (Connection timed out)
>     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_212]   at
>   java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_212]   at
>   java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_212]   at
>   java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_212]   at
>   java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_212]   at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_212]   at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_212]   at java.net.Socket.(Socket.java:434)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_212]   at java.net.Socket.(Socket.java:211)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_212]   at com.jcraft.jsch.Util.createSocket(Util.java:343)
>   ~[com.jcraft.jsch-0.1.54.jar:na]  ... 10 common frames omitted

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This looks like a problem when CDAP tries to ssh to the remote cluster at the start of a program run. This is normally due to firewalls blocking ingress traffic to port 22 and can be fixed by creating a firewall rule that allows it.

See https://cloud.google.com/data-fusion/docs/how-to/create-instance#before_you_begin for more information about steps that should be taken to ensure the Data Fusion instance has the access it needs.